# directive watch gets triggered when inserting new items

Tags: angularjs

I have a table, where I from the server can push new rows to the client. On some of the columns I'm using a directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('highlighter', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        model: '=highlighter'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var nv = parseFloat(newValue);
            var ov = parseFloat(oldValue);
            if (nv !== ov) {
                if (nv > ov) {
                    // apply class
                    element.addClass('highlightUp');

                    // auto remove after some delay
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element.removeClass('highlightUp');
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                    // apply class
                    element.addClass('highlightDown');

                    // auto remove after some delay
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.removeClass('highlightDown');
                    }, 2000);
                }

            }
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

The problem with this is that when I push out new rows into the table from server side some of them triggers the watch, even though it's the first time and nothing has changed.

```
<tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="row in vm.rows
                    | filter:searchText
                    | filter:row.IsVisible
                    | orderBy:sortRows:vm.sortReverse
                    | itemsPerPage:vm.pagination.pageSize track by $index"
                    data-ng-click="toggleNode(row)"
                    data-ng-show="row.IsVisible">
                    <td ng-repeat="column in vm.columns">
                        <span ng-if="shouldBeHighlighted">{{renderCellValue(row, column)}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

It's a little bit hard to recreate this in plunker, but does anyony now how the watch can be triggered when the items are inserted first time? And where the values (newValue, oldValue) come from? Because the oldValue is wrong..

EDIT: Just to be little clearer. `newValue` and `oldValue` is non of them `undefined` when I push out new rows.

Comment: `oldVal` and `newVal` both start as `undefined`.  So when you set your data for the first time, of course the watch is going to fire, because `newVal` is going to have actual data.

Comment: When I debug I can see that its not `undefined`. And then it goes forward and put the css class on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was kind a bad mistake by me...Of course it gets all messed up when I change the array where I hold the rows, the `track by $index` get messed up..I changed it to `track by row.Id`

Answer (score 0):

it could be that the oldValue is undefined/null, but then parseFloat turns it into something processable. maybe try to examine the oldValue's behaviour around parseFloat?